# Disable button if conditions does not meet jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a condition that is if check box is checked and email field ends with @xyz.edu, then the submit button should be enabled and also, if checkbox is not checked and if email field is contains @xyz.edu, even then button should be disabled.

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m10 offset-m1 offset-s2">
    <input id="email" name="email" th:value="${user.email}" type="email" class="validate" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m10 offset-m1 offset-s2">
        <input id = "checkbox" name="userRole" value="ADMIN" type="checkbox" class="validate" />
        <label>Admin</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m10 offset-m1 offset-s2">
        <button id="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" disabled = "disabled" name="action" value="signup">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
 $('#checkbox').click(function(){

           if(this.checked)
           {
              var email = $('#email').val();
              var str = "@sjsu.edu"
              if(email.match("@sjsu.edu$"))
              {

                $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
              }
              else
              {
                $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
              }
           }
    });
```

So when I give the input as @gmail.com and check the checkbox, button remains disabled. Now if I again change just the input field, it enables the button, even if condition is not met. Can someone help me

Here's my link to code: https://jsfiddle.net/chandham/e5g0m7o9/

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/

Comment: @epascarello, I am to disable the button the first time. If I change any input value, button automatically gets enabled

Comment: And you are not using the correct method to disable an element as the jQuery FAQ states. And if you want the text box to change it, than add a change event to the input.

Answer (score 0):

Extract your validation code to a separate function - i.e. the code where you check that `#checkbox` is checked and `#email` ends in @sjsu.edu. Then bind this function to the event handlers for the checkbox and the email's change events, like so:

```
$("#email, #checkbox").change(updateSubmitButtonState);

function updateSubmitButtonState() {
    // Code to validate inputs
}
```

Edit: [Working JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rq46bj4/5/)

I also added an event handler for the page load event so it starts in the correct state.

Comment: There's one more condition. If I give email other than @sjsu.edu and if I don't click on checkbox, button should be enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#checkbox,#email').on('input', function(e) {
    var checked = $('#checkbox').is(':checked');
    var endsWith = /@xyz\.edu$/.test($('#email').val());
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', !((!checked && !endsWith) || (checked && endsWith)));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s12 m10 offset-m1 offset-s2">
  <input id="email" name="email" value="abc@xyz.edu" type="email" class="validate" />
  <label for="email">Email</label>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12 m10 offset-m1 offset-s2">
    <input id="checkbox" name="userRole" value="ADMIN" type="checkbox" class="validate" />
    <label>Admin</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12 m10 offset-m1 offset-s2">
    <button id="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" disabled="disabled" name="action" value="signup">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: these are my requirements:
**Conditions** - 
xyz.edu and checkbox checked - button enabled
xyz.edu and checkbox not checked - button disabled
gmail.com(other than xyz.edu) and checkbox not checked - button enabled
gmail.com(other than xyz.edu) and checkbox  checked - button disabled